# Showing that reward function is bounded (dynamic programing)

Tags: mathematical-economics, dynamic-programming

I have the following dynamic programming problem:

$$\max_{\{x_t,y_{t+1}\}_{t=0}^\infty}\sum_{t=0}^\infty \beta^tu(F(x_t)-y_{t+1})\;\;\;\;\;\text{s.t}\;\;\;\;y_{t+1}\in\Gamma(x_t)$$

where $\Gamma(x)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}_{+}\mid 0\le y\le F(x)\}$, and the functions $u$ and $F$ have the following properties:

1. $u:\mathbb{R}_{+}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, strictly increasing, and strictly concave;
2. $F:\mathbb{R}_{+}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, strictly increasing, and concave;
3. $F(0)=0$;
4. And there exists $\bar{x}>0$ such that:

- If $x\in[0,\bar{x}]$ then $F(x)\in[x,\bar{x}]$.
- If $x>\bar{x}$ then $F(x)<x$.

I've got to show that the function $G(x,y)\equiv u(F(x)-y)$ is bounded over the set $A\equiv\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}_{+}\times\mathbb{R}_{+}\mid y\in\Gamma(x)\}$.

What I have tried: Let $(x,y)\in A$, then $y\in\Gamma(x)$. First, by definition the functions $u$ and $F$ clearly $G$ is bounded below. Now in order to show that $G$ is bounded above, I noticed that the set of images $G(x,\Gamma(x))$ is compact *in the second argument* because $G$ is continuous and $\Gamma(x)$ is compact, i.e. given $x$ we have that the function $G(x,\cdot)$ is bounded in $\Gamma(x)$.

Now, trying to show that $G$ is bounded above in $x$ (i.e. in the *first* argument) has proven to be more involved, I'm trying to use the fourth property shown above about the existence of $\bar{x}$, where we have two cases, if $x\in[0, \bar{x}]$ then clearly $G(x,y)\le u(F(\bar{x})-y)\le u(F(\bar{x}))$. But when considering $x>\bar{x}$ we have $F(x)<x$, thus $G(x,y)<u(x-y)$ which does not show that $G$ is bounded since the "bound" still depends on $x$ which is in a unbounded space $(\bar{x},\infty)$.

I think there must be a trick with $F(x)<x$ but I have not been able to see it, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The function $u(F(x)-y)$ is not necessarily bounded on $A$. For example, if $u(x) = F(x) = \sqrt{x}$ then:
$$
u(F(x)-y) = \sqrt{\sqrt{x}-y},
$$
Taking $y = 0$, this gives $u(F(x)) = \sqrt{\sqrt{x}}$, which is clearly unbounded in $x$.

The problem you are looking at is the following:
$$
\max_{(x_t, y_t)_{t = 0}^\infty} \sum_{t = 0}^\infty \beta^t u(F(x_t) - y_{t+1})  \text{ s.t. } y_{t+1} \in [0, F(x_t)].
$$
Notice that this problem is not well defined. In particular, given that $u$ is strictly increasing, the best choice for $y_{t+1}$ is to set it equal to zero at every instance $t$. This gives the payoff function
$$
\sum_{t = 0}^\infty \beta^t u(F(x_t)),
$$
which is clearly increasing in $x_t$ (as both $u$ and $F$ are strictly increasing). As such, the best thing to do is to set $x_t$ as large as possible (so equal to $+ \infty$). This means that your maximisation problem has no solution.

Now, assume that you have a better behaving model, for example, $y_t = x_t$. This then gives the problem:
$$
\max_{(x_t)_{t = 0}^\infty} \sum_{t = 0}^\infty \beta^t u(F(x_t) - x_{t+1})  \text{ s.t. } x_{t+1} \in [0, F(x_t)].
$$
The function $u(F(x)-y)$ is still unbounded, but now you can show that the objective function $\sum_{t=0}^\infty \beta^t u(F(x_t) - x_{t+1})$ is bounded for every feasible path. Let $\partial u(0)$ be a supdifferential (derivative) for $u$ at zero. Then, using concavity of $u$, we have:
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{t = 0}^n \beta^t u(F(x_t) - x_{t+1}) &\le \sum_{t = 0}^n \beta^t \left(u(0) + \partial u(0)[F(x_t) - x_{t+1}]\right),\\
&= u(0) \sum_{t = 0}^n \beta^t + \partial u(0) \underbrace{\sum_{t = 0}^n \beta^t [F(x_t) - x_{t+1}]}_{=A}.
\end{align*}
$$
Now, $F(x) \le \overline{x} + x$ (if $x \le \overline{x}$ then $F(x) \le \overline{x}$ and if $x \ge \overline{x}$, then $F(x) \le x$). So,
$$
\begin{align*}
A &\le \sum_{t = 0}^n \beta^t [\overline{x} + x_t - x_{t+1}],\\
&= \overline{x} \sum_{t = 0}^n \beta^t + \underbrace{\sum_{t = 0}^n \beta^t (x_t - x_{t+1})}_{=B}
\end{align*}
$$
Then,
$$
\begin{align*}
B &= \sum_{t = 0}^n \beta^t (x_t - x_{t+1}),\\
&=x_0 \underbrace{- x_1 + \beta x_1}_{\le 0} \underbrace{- \beta x_2 + \beta^2 x_2}_{\le 0} \underbrace{- \beta^2 x_3 + \,\,}_{\le 0} \ldots \underbrace{\,\, + \beta^n x_n}_{\le 0} - \beta^n x_{n+1},\\
&\le x_0 - \beta^n x_{n+1} \le x_0
\end{align*}
$$
Putting it all together, we obtain the bound:
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{t = 0}^n \beta^t u(F(x_t) - x_{t+1}) & \le (u(0) + \partial u(0) \overline{x}) \sum_{t = 0}^n \beta^t + \partial u(0) x_0
\end{align*}
$$
Taking the limit $t \to \infty$, the right hand side converges to $\frac{u(0) + \partial u(0) \overline{x}}{1 - \beta} + \partial u(0) x_0$ (a fixed number).